# regarding showing multiple locations in google map in android

Tags: android

I have to implement google map in android.Now the problem i am facing is I have to show multiple locations.I have shown single location in google map in android stimulator.Can anyone tell me how to implement it??

Answer (score 0):

pass multiple values and get corresponding geopoint values and add geopoint to overlay.

Comment: Can you give any example for that?